# Simple way to calculate $n! \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the exercise "Calculate $10! \pmod{13}$".

I have the following two approaches to solve the exercise:

1. Brute force approach

$$
1! \equiv 1 \pmod{13} \\
2! = 2 \cdot 1! \equiv 2 \cdot 1 \equiv 2 \pmod{13} \\
3! = 3 \cdot 2! \equiv 3 \cdot 2 \equiv 6 \pmod{13} \\
\cdots \\
10! = 10 \cdot 9! \equiv 10 \cdot 11 = 110 = 8 \cdot 13 + 6 \equiv 6 \pmod{13}
$$

2. Approach using [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem):

Wilson's theorem states that
$$p \in \mathbb{P} \implies (p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$$

For my exercise:
$$13 \in \mathbb{P} \implies \\
(13-1)! = 12! = 10!\cdot 11 \cdot 12 \equiv -1 \pmod{13} \implies \\
10! \equiv -(11 \cdot 12)^{-1} \pmod{13}
$$
Using Fermat's little theorem
$$
a^p \equiv a \pmod p \implies a^{p-2} \cdot a \cdot a \equiv a^{-1} \cdot a \cdot a \pmod p \implies a^{p-2} \equiv a^{-1} \pmod p \\
$$
For my exercise:
$$10! = -(11 \cdot 12)^{-1} \equiv \\
-(11 \cdot 12)^{13-2} = -(11 \cdot 12)^{11} \equiv \\
-(-2 \cdot -1)^{11} = -2^{11} = \\
-2^6 \cdot 2^5 \equiv 1 \cdot 2^5 = \\
32 \equiv 6 \pmod{13} \\
$$

Both approaches look quite bulky.

In the first method I have to make $O(n)$ multiplications.

In the second method I have to make $O(p-n)$ multiplications which is smaller than in the first method, but also can be huge number for big $p$ and $n$.

Is there a way to improve my solution?

Is there an efficient way to calculate $n! \pmod p$ for big $n$ and $p$?

Comment: I suppose, for a start, it ought to depend on how big $n$ is relative to $p$, right?

Comment: The larger difference between $p$ and $n$, the smaller improvement the Wilson't theorem gives to the solution. But anyway, in both my approaches I have to make a lot of multiplications.

It looks like that some calculations can be done in modular arithmetic in much more efficient way than in ordinary arithmetic. And what I am looking for is some way to calculate $n! \pmod p$ in more efficient way, without doing such amount of multiplications.

Comment: For example, naive calculation of $a^n$ requires $O(n)$ multiplications, but using improved approach it can be done in $O(\log(n))$ multiplications. Using Ferma's little theorem it's possible to reduce number of multiplications while calculating $a^n \pmod p$ a lot. And so on. I'm looking for similar method to simplify calculation of $n! \pmod p$.

Comment: For any odd prime $p$ $$(p-3)!\equiv \frac{p-1}{2}\pmod{p}$$ and in order to compute $n!\pmod{p}$ it is enough to compute $q\pmod{p}$ for any prime $q\leq n$. Plus, we know in advance what $(p-1)!$ and $\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!$ are $\pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with your Wilson's Theorem approach but finish off differently.  Note that $12\equiv -1$ and $11\equiv -2 \pmod{13}$ and that these two numbers have easy inverses $(-2)(-7) \equiv 1$ and $(-1)(-1) \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$, so

$$10! \equiv -(11)^{-1}(12)^{-1} \equiv -(-2)^{-1}(-1)^{-1} \equiv -(-7)(-1) \equiv 6 \pmod{13}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Semi brute force.  $14\equiv 1 \mod 13$ so toss out $2,7$.  $27 \equiv 1$ so toss out $3,9$.  $40 \equiv 1$ so toss out $4,10$ and $8,5$.  What do we have left.

Just $6$.  $10! \equiv 6\mod 13$

because $10! =(2*7)(3*9)(4*10)6 (5*8)\equiv 6 \mod 13$

Hmm, that's not very satisfying, is it.